# Disable firewall, ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

How can I disable firewall on ubuntu, or how can I check which ports are listening, and how can I add some new ports to be listened to?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to see if the firewall is running

```
> sudo /sbin/iptables -L        
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
> sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

if you see anything else in the output except default policies that read ACCEPT then you have a firewall on

Answer (score 1):

Check which ports are listening:

```
netstat -tlunp
```

Ubuntu 9.04 doesn't have any firewall by default, did you enable any?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just can't open any https websites .. So my first guess is firewall?

Comment: I would say firewall is not likely to be your problem. You cannot access websites from that machine or run a  web server in that machine?

Comment: I'm trying to access the server machine from another machine.. not from the same machine if that is what you're implying

Comment: Sorry, can't follow, which machine is which? Can you name them or something?